# Angular test fail on gitlab pipeline

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci

I've got my pipeline failing due to a front unit test which doesn't success in the pipeline while locally with yarn test command I don't have any failure.

Here is my test file :

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

describe('BsGapRepoComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BsGapRepoComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [SharedModule, NoopAnimationsModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

My component file :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-compo',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class myComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

As you can see it's a new component.

And here is the log faliure from gitlab :

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) MyComponent should create FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get_container_ul()[0].className') thrown
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get_container_ul()[0].className') thrown
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 112 of 185 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 1 min 25.792 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) MyComponent should create FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get_container_ul()[0].className') thrown
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get_container_ul()[0].className') thrown
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) MyComponent should create FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get_container_ul()[0].className') thrown
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.get_container_ul()[0].className') thrown
```

I'm using Angular v8

Thank you

Comment: have you added --headless flag

Comment: Hi, no I did'nt, I don't know what is this for

Answer (score 1):

you can’t run a browser on a server, **Headless Chrome** is a useful tool for running automated tests in environments where it isn’t practical to actually launch a browser, so try to add this config in your **karma.conf.js**

```
browsers: ['Chrome_no_sandbox'],
customLaunchers: {
 Chrome_no_sandbox: {
 base: 'Chrome',
 flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--single-run']
 }
}
```

the other possibility is to use Run **PhantomJS**

- install **karma-phantomjs-launcher**
- add PhantomJS to the plugings

  ```
  plugins: [
   require('karma-jasmine'),
   require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
   require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'), // here
   require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
   require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
   require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
  ],
  ```
- and make phantomJs the browser

  ```
  browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
  singleRun: true
  ```

Comment: Hi, I've already set up PhantomJS, I tried with the headless flag but still the same issue, currently the only way I found to solve the probleme is to comment / remove the test concerned. I will try to set singleRun to ```true```

Comment: PhantomJs is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

try to run `npm run build-prod` in your project directory, sometimes if you fix if any error thrown by this command will solve your GitLab pipeline issue, because `ng serve` command only try to run angular application and if any error comes in executing app will throw an error but ng build will check all Tslint errors, logical errors and throw that error to you.